# How to get the remaining threads in JR?

Tags: java, frameworks

I'm new to JR and I'm creating 2 types of process (let's call process A and B), there are some rules like the process B need to meet 2 process A to exit.

My problem is how to collect the remaining process at the end. For example if there is still 3 process B waiting to meet a process A, I want to get thoses 3 process.

Here is how I create my process:

```java
process A ((int ppid = 0; ppid < nbProcessA; ++ppid)){
    for( int i = 0; i < iterProcessA; ++i){
        ...
    }
}
```

and it's basically the same for process B.

Comment: Your question can be expanded a little bit to help providing and answer. Are the processes system process or just threads you call processes? Where do you store those processes. Is it possible to show us a working example? 
Those can help people that will reach you to identify what is your problem faster!

Comment: I assume they are just thread and I don't really have a working example since I'm trying to find how to collect the remaining ones

Comment: perfect! then you are probably doing something like `new Thread()` . Try storing those responses in a list so you will access methods like `Thread#isAlive` in order to do what you need.

Comment: no with JR I don't make a ```new Thread()``` but only this method call ```process A(....)``` [here is the JR website](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~olsson/research/jr)

Comment: ah then thats my bad as I was checking the tags and you had only java ( jr tag doesn't exist ) . If I think of something i will come back to you

Comment: Yes I had this problem with the tags because JR doesn't exist, I'll add framework in the tags